# Kick me back into my current SMS conversation from my app?

Tags: objective-c, sms, message

My app basically lets me go in and copy an image to a clipboard.  I'd like to then automatically open the user to their current SMS conversation in the Messages app so they can paste it in.

So far the only way I know of doing this is using the sms: protocol, which does get me to the messages app, but it will only let me go to an empty search field or to a preset number.  Is there a way to just open the messages app?  It would take you to the most recent conversation by default.

As a backup, is there a way of telling the number of the user's most recent conversation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Apple Approved method of opening the Messages app from your application, programmatically.